# class not found error when migrating code from Eclipse Juno to Kepler

Tags: android, eclipse-kepler

When I run the Android app from the Eclipse IDE on my Mobile phone, it compiles fine, and comes up with the main activity. When I press one of the buttons to bring up another activity, I get error 'Link of class ... failed'

'Unable to find superclass...'

'could not find class ... referenced from ... '

My code is unchanged, and it does not find the activity class in the linker, in spite of it compiling fine, and is present in the manifest.

This code worked as is on Juno.
Any ideas what could have changed?

Thanks

Adrian